# Vue 3: Why variable watcher doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, watch, vue-sfc

I have like this code in my project:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const num = ref(null)

// Some condition
if(true) {
  // Doesn't works. Why?
  num.value = 1

  // Works
  //setTimeout(() => {
  //  num.value = 2
  //})
}
// Simple watcher  
watch(num, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  console.log("Num changed to: ", newVal)
})
</script>
```

My `watcher` doesn't work when I set `num.value = 1`. How I can fix this to work?
But when I run with `setTimeout` it's work

**Demo project** [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add the watcher after you set it to 1, so there is no chance for it to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

First you change the value of `num` to 1, then you declare the watcher. To make it work, you should first call the watcher then change the value.

The reason why `setTimeout` works, is that it pushes the callback, it receives, into the event loop. In javascript you have this thing called event loop and a javascript environment constantly looks if there is anything pushed to it, which can be executed (Similar to a message queue). However callbacks in the event loop are not executed before the current stack is finished executing.

For your case it means that the end of the code inside your script is execute, the watcher is set and only then the callback you gave to `setTimeout` is executed.